# Disabling cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, error-handling

I know that my gfg[item[0] + 1][item[1]] does not exist, but I need to run my code further:

```
 arrayfirstword.forEach(item => {
                if(typeof(gfg[item[0] + 1][item[1]]) !== undefined){
                    console.log(1);
                }
```

Is there a way to disable this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You have to adjust your code and make sure you do not access things from an undefined value:

```
arrayfirstword.forEach(item => {

                if(item && gfg && item[0] && item[1] && gfg[item[0] + 1] && typeof(gfg[item[0] + 1][item[1]]) !== undefined){
                    console.log(1);
                }
```

To void repeating expressions:

```
arrayfirstword.forEach(item => {
                if (!item || !item[0] || !item[1] || !gfg) return;
                let key = item[0] + 1;
                let val = gfg[key];
                if (val && val[item[1]]) {
                    console.log(1);
                }
```

In this case it is uglier but if the condition gets more complicated it might be better to split it into 5-6 lines instead of having a huge nested complicated condition.

Comment: Thanks bruh but I didn't get the point, you are still checking the value of an undefined variable?

Comment: @s662720h_uu `||` and `&&` are lazy. They stop evaluating the condition when they can return the value. For example `true || someFunc()` will **not** run `someFunc()` because `true || anything === true`. Same with `false && someFunc()` will **not** run `someFunc()` because `false && anything === false`. `undefined.attribute` is an error so you can avoid it by doing `if (v && v.attribute)` if `v` is undefined `v && v.attribute` only checks `v` since `undefined` is "falsey"and it will not try to get `attribute` from `undefined`